Difference between "and" and "or" inequalities in domain and range

Hi,
I am having a hard time distinguishing the difference between "and" and "or" when finding domain and range using inequality notation. If you see this pic above, I am confused of the difference. Can someone please distinguish why domain uses an "Or" inequality and why range uses an "and" inequality in this graph?

This seems like a mistake. They should both say "or". Membership in the union of two sets is equivalent to membership in each connected by the "or" conjunction:
$$
x \in A \cup B 
\quad\iff\quad 
x \in A \quad\text{or}\quad x \in B
$$
Note that in mathematics, logic, etc., this is inclusive "or" meaning that both conditions can be true.
There's an analogous statement for "and". Membership in the intersection of two sets is equivalent to membership in each connected by the "and" conjunction:
$$
x \in A \cap B 
\quad\iff\quad 
x \in A \quad\text{and}\quad x \in B
$$
It's always true that $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$ and similarly for $B$. Intuitively, this means that intersection takes away from a set and makes the result smaller since there are stricter criteria for membership ("this and that"); whereas, union adds to a set and makes the result bigger since there are looser criteria for membership ("this or that").

In your example, a $y$-value is in the range of the function if and only if it is in either the interval $[-4, -2]$ or $[2, 4]$. In fact, if we read the word "and" literally there, any member $y$ in that intersection would have to simultaneously satisfy $y \leq -2$ and $2 \leq y$, which is impossible.

Thank you. That is what i thought. It didn't make sense with the “and”

Both expressions say the same thing in slightly different ways. The distinction is subtle and confusing.
The implicit subject in the sentence about the domain is
the value of $x$. It is in one of those intervals or the other.
The implicit subject in the sentence about the range is the whole range, as a set. It consists of two intervals: one and the other.
The author carelessly switched their mental picture, and so did you a disservice.
